# Parse RESET API for Login

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I am using Parse REST Login API but I am getting invalid login parameter error. Then I tried log in example from https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#users-logging-in

```
> curl -X GET \   
       -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <App_ID>" \   
       -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <REST_ID>" \   
       -H "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" \   
       -G \   
       --data-urlencode 'username=<username>' \  
       --data-urlencode 'password=<password>' \   
        https://api.parse.com/1/login
```

I used above curl command as it is (replacing AppID/RESTID/username and password) on terminal and I got same error

```
{"code":101,"error":"invalid login parameters"}
```

I believe above command should work as it is on terminal. Did anyone used REST API for log in?

Comment: Without telling us your credentials, I'm not sure what you expect as an answer

Comment: use the parse dashboard to double check the Id and the key value... 
use the DB to verify that the user exists... use curl -vvv to dump more of the protocol / log